# Remove duplicates from NSMutableDictionary within NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have `NSMutableArray` i.e books which contains objects. These object are  `NSMutableDictionay`, each object is a key value pair of 3 things i.e. id, name, username. Let there is a case that i have 3 objects having values !

```
 - object1 = id->1, name->Hilal, username->hilalbaig ;
 - object2 = id->2, name->Ali,  username->alibaig ;
 - object3 = id->3, name->Jalal, username->hilalbaig ;
```

all these object(`NSMutableDictionay`) are in array(`NSMutableArray`).

Now my question is that i want to remove duplicates from it as `object1` and `object2` are duplicates because both have `username -> hilalbaig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Linq to ObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC) you can remove the duplicates as follows:

```
NSMutableArray* source = // your array of dictionaries
NSArray* uniqueItems = [source distinct:^id(id dictionary) {
    return [dictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
}];
```

A [distinct](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#distinct) method returns distinct items from an array. The key-selector block allows you to determine how equality is evaluated. In the above example you can see that two dictionaries are considered equal if they have the same 'username'.